# Css background-image in div doesn't work

Tags: css, background-image

The HTML:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#header{
    height: 280;
    width: 850;
    background-image: url('/image.png');
}
```

I don't see anything in this `div`; the background doesn't show up. I have tested the url to make sure it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a unit for the value on the `width` and `height` properties for the background-image to appear. The only scenario where its okay to leave out the value is when your specifying 0

Examples of unit you can use: `px` `%` `pt` `em` `rem` `ch` `vmin`

[Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/)

Comment: Ooooh. I completely forgot that. Silly mistake. Whoops.

Comment: If Lotus's answer worked for you, it would be great if you accepted his answer :)